# Mandatory permissions from apps with the last version of JB4A versions. (salesforce marketing Cloud)

Tags: mobilesdk, ios, android

Using JB4A SDKs (provided by Salesforce marketing cloud) What permissions are mandatory and for which versions of iOS and Android.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The required permissions can be found on the documentation page titled [SDK IMPLEMENTATION - Google](http://exacttarget.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html)

I'll list them here for reference, but these permissions are valid for version 4.0.4 of the SDK released July 2015 and may change for future versions:

```
   <permission
       android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature" />
   <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Additionally, you will need the following permissions if you implement [Geolocation Services](http://exacttarget.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/location/geolocation.html):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```